# PYTHON 2.6 XML.ETREE to output single quote for attributes instead of double quote

Tags: python, xml, lxml, python-2.6

i got the following code :

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.6  

from lxml import etree  

n = etree.Element('test')    
n.set('id','1234')  
print etree.tostring(n)
```

the output generate is `<test id="1234"/>`
but i want `<test id='1234'/>`

can someone help ?

Comment: Why do you care? It shouldn't matter; double quotes are as valid as single quotes.

Comment: I know that both are valid but you have to care when application does not respect this :-(

Comment: @mzjn: Or you have to care when the attribute **must** contain a lot of `"` characters and you don't want to type `&quot;` for each and everyone of them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I checked the documentation and found no reference for single/double-quote option.

I think your only recourse is `print etree.tostring(n).replace('"', "'")`

**Update**

Given:

```
from lxml import etree
n = etree.Element('test')
n.set('id', "Zach's not-so-good answer")
```

my original answer could output malformed XML because of unbalanced apostrophes:

```
<test id='Zach's not-so-good answer'></test>
```

Martijn suggested `print etree.tostring(n).replace("'", '&apos;').replace('"', "'")` to address the problem:

```
<test id='Zach&apos;s not-so-good answer'></test>
```

Comment: This is incredibly unreliable.

Comment: No doubt it's unreliable, which is why I used the word "recourse". Still, the OP was up against the wall with a crappy XML parser/processor, and this solution did the trick.

Comment: This is not really a safe approach, as single quotes in the attribute value are not escaped. You *can* first replace all single quotes with `&apos;`, and *then* replace the double quotes.