# Generating Xml using python

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing

Kindly have a look at below code i am using this to generate a xml using python .

```python
from lxml import etree


# Some dummy text
conn_id = 5
conn_name = "Airtelll"
conn_desc = "Largets TRelecome"
ip = "192.168.1.23"

# Building the XML tree
# Note how attributes and text are added, using the Element methods
# and not by concatenating strings as in your question
root = etree.Element("ispinfo")
child = etree.SubElement(root, 'connection',
                 number = str(conn_id),
                 name = conn_name,
                 desc = conn_desc)
subchild_ip = etree.SubElement(child, 'ip_address')
subchild_ip.text = ip

# and pretty-printing it
print etree.tostring(root, pretty_print=True)
```

This will produce:

```
<ispinfo>
  <connection desc="Largets TRelecome" number="5" name="Airtelll">
    <ip_address>192.168.1.23</ip_address>
  </connection>
</ispinfo>
```

But i want it to be like  :

```
<ispinfo>
  <connection desc="Largets TRelecome" number='1' name="Airtelll">
    <ip_address>192.168.1.23</ip_address>
  </connection>
</ispinfo>
```

Mean number attribute should be come in a single quote .Any idea ....How can i achieve this

Comment: guys do let me know if any clarification required

Comment: You mean you want the attribute value in single quotes instead of double quotes?

Comment: If by "comma" you mean "quote" and by "1" you mean "5", then you shouldn't care. There's no semantic difference between the two in XML.

Comment: @janne Exactly i want  attribute value in single quotes instead of double quotes

Comment: @larsmans  5 is in double quote while 1 is in single quote

Comment: Has been asked before in [PYTHON 2.6 XML.ETREE to output single quote for attributes instead of double quote](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8730950/222914), but as larsmans wrote, you should not care.

Comment: @JanneKarila You know that not all XML-consumers are properly conformant? If anything, I would say that non-conformance seems to be the norm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no flag in lxml to do this, so you have to resort to manual manipulation.

```
import re
re.sub(r'number="([0-9]+)"',r"number='\1'", etree.tostring(root, pretty_print=True))
```

However, why do you want to do this? As there is no difference other than cosmetics.